# Create list from generator

Tags: python, list, generator

Is there a shortcut to creating a list from a generator?  I'm doing this now:

```
list_form = [ item for item in some_generator ]
```

I need to sort the data before iteration, thus can't use the generator directly in my loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, use the [`list()` constructor](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list):

```
list_form = list(some_generator)
```

`list()` takes any iterable and adds its values to a newly created list object.

However, if you need a *sorted* list, you may as well use [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) directly:

```
sorted_form = sorted(some_generator)
```

Comment: Dammit, I should have thought of `sorted`. I made my answer more _dramatic_ than yours though :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list()`:

```
l = list(generator)
```

The blinding proof (yes, I feel dramatic):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a = [['1', '2'], ['a']]
>>> gen = chain.from_iterable(a)
>>> gen
<itertools.chain object at 0x027EE3F0>
>>> list(gen)
['1', '2', 'a']
```

If that was too dramatic (using `itertools` to prove a simple point):

```
>>> xrange(10)
xrange(10)
>>> list(xrange(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use:

```
list_form = list(some_generator)
```